# Strict weak ordering of different types in stl algorithms

Tags: c++, stl, c++11

I have a class that defines a strict weak ordering with other types, and I would like to use comparison-based algorithms on a container of that class (e.g. std::upper_bound).

The standard defines that the container's forward iterator value type should be that of the comparable type, so the following doesn't compile:

```
template<typename T>
class Foo {
public:
    bool operator<(const T& _val) { return val < _val; }
    //operator T() { return val; } // uncommenting this solves the problem
private:
    T val;
};

void bar() {
    vector<Foo<int>> foos(10);
    auto i_lb = std::lower_bound(foos.begin(), foos.end(), 17); // compiles and works, though I don't know why
    auto i_eq = std::equal_range(foos.begin(), foos.end(), 17); // error! not convertible to int
}
```

I couldn't find a way of using the algorithm version that accepts the predicate (also requires the types to be the same). Defining a conversion operator makes this example work, but it's not always right to define one. What is the right way of making such a comparison work?

Incidentally, replacing std::equal_range with std::lower_bound works, but I cannot figure out why.

Answer (score 3):

The equal_range will have to compare the values both ways to determine if they are equal

> A value, `a`, is considered equivalent to another, `b`, when `(!(a<b) && !(b<a))`

lower_bound just has to find one end of the range.

You comparison just works for `Foo < T`, and not for `T < Foo`.

Comment: I know that operator< is not enough for equal range or upper bound, but I don't know how it was matched for the lower bound algorithm

Comment: what if I define two overloads of a function, comp(Foo,T) and comp(T,Foo). Will that function work for the second version of the algorithms?

Comment: Lower_bound just has to compare the elements one way, like `while (a < b) try_next`. As soon as the comparison is false, the position has been found.

Comment: If you have two comparison operators, the code will compile. I'm not totally sure that it defines a strict weak ordering though.

Comment: I tried that, but the compiler cannot deduce which overload of comp() to use. It's not the elegant solution I was looking for anyway

Comment: I think you misunderstood the suggestion. Define `template<typename T> bool operator<(const T&, const Foo<T>&)` as a non-member function, so the `b<a` comparison works.

Comment: Alternatively, define a functor class that has overloaded `operator()(const T&, const Foo<T>&)` and `operator()(const Foo<T>&, const T&)` and pass an instance of that functor type to the algorithm